# Centralize swaggers in api gateway returns "Failed to load remote configuration."

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, spring-cloud

I created a discovery server using Eureka, I added a gateway and 2 webservices. All
I added 2 webservices and a gateway. My service do correctly register to Eureka.
I am using :

- spring boot 3.2.1
- spring cloud 2023.0.0

I want to have all swagger documentation available in the gateway.

**On webservices I added the following dependencies:**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

**On each I also add OpenApiDefinition annotation:**

```
...
@OpenAPIDefinition(info =
    @Info(
            title = "User Management and authentication Webservice",
            description = "This web service allow register, log in and update user profile",
            version = "1.0",
            contact = @Contact(
                    name = "Technical Service",
                    url = "https://www.******/",
                    email = "****@****"
            ),
            termsOfService = "https://www.*****",
            license = @License(name =  "Apache 2.0", url = "http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0")
))
public class UserWsApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(UserWsApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

On user webservice I added the following setting (extract):

```
server.port=${PORT:0}
spring.application.name=users-ws
springdoc.show-actuator=false
```

The second web service:

```
server.port=${PORT:0}
spring.application.name=licences-ws
springdoc.show-actuator=false
```

**On the gateway, I added the following dependency**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webflux-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webflux-ui</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

**I configured my routes**

```
# remote openapi
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].id=openapi
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].uri = http://localhost:${server.port}
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].predicates[0]=Path=/v3/api-docs/**
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].filters[0]=RewritePath=/v3/api-docs/(?<segment>.*), /$\{segment}/v3/api-docs


# status public page
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[1].id=users-ws-status
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[1].uri = lb://users-ws
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[1].predicates[0]=Path=/users/status
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[1].predicates[1]=Method=GET
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[1].filters[0]=RemoveRequestHeader=Cookie
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[1].filters[1]=RewritePath=/users-ws/users/status, /users/status

# user registration routes do not need filter
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[2].id=users-ws
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[2].uri = lb://users-ws
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[2].predicates[0]=Path=/users
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[2].predicates[1]=Method=POST
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[2].filters[0]=RemoveRequestHeader=Cookie
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[2].filters[1]=RewritePath=/users-ws/(?<segment>.*), /$\{segment}

spring.cloud.gateway.routes[3].id = users-ws-login
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[3].uri = lb://users-ws
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[3].predicates[0]=Path=/users/login
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[3].predicates[1]=Method=POST
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[3].filters[0]=RemoveRequestHeader=Cookie
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[3].filters[1]=RewritePath=/users-ws/(?<segment>.*), /$\{segment}

# reset request
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[4].id = users-ws-auth-reset-request
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[4].uri = lb://users-ws
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[4].predicates[0]=Path=/users/password-reset-request
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[4].predicates[1]=Method=POST
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[4].filters[0]=RemoveRequestHeader=Cookie
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[4].filters[1]=RewritePath=/users-ws/(?<segment>.*), /$\{segment}

# reset password validation: we send get request with request param named token
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[5].id = users-ws-auth-reset-validation
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[5].uri = lb://users-ws
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[5].predicates[0]=Path=/users/password-reset
#spring.cloud.gateway.routes[5].predicates[1]=Query=token
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[5].predicates[1]=Method=POST
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[5].filters[0]=RemoveRequestHeader=Cookie
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[5].filters[1]=RewritePath=/users-ws/(?<segment>.*), /$\{segment}

# user management routes do  need filter
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[6].id=users-management-ws
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[6].uri=lb://users-ws
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[6].predicates[0]=Path=/users/**
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[6].predicates[1]=Method=GET,PUT,DELETE
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[6].predicates[2]=Header=Authorization, Bearer (.*)
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[6].filters[0]=RemoveRequestHeader=Cookie
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[6].filters[1]=AuthorizationHeaderFilter
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[6].filters[2]=RewritePath=/users-ws/(?<segment>.*), /$\{segment}

# configuring filter for actuator
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[7].id = users-ws-actuator
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[7].uri = lb://users-ws
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[7].predicates[0]=Path=/users-ws/actuator/**
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[7].predicates[1]=Method=GET
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[7].filters[0]=RemoveRequestHeader=Cookie
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[7].filters[1]=RewritePath=/users-ws/(?<segment>.*), /$\{segment}


# user registration routes do not need filter
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[8].id=licences-ws
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[8].uri = lb://licences-ws
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[8].predicates[0]=Path=/users/**
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[8].predicates[1]=Method=POST,GET
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[8].filters[0]=RemoveRequestHeader=Cookie
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[8].filters[1]=RewritePath=/licences-ws/(?<segment>.*), /$\{segment}
```

**I also added then following settings for open api doc**

```
springdoc.swagger-ui.use-root-path=true
springdoc.api-docs.enabled=true
#springdoc.api-docs.path=/api-docs
springdoc.swagger-ui.enabled=true
springdoc.swagger-ui.path=/swagger-ui.html
springdoc.swagger-ui.config-url=/v3/api-docs/swagger-config

springdoc.swagger-ui.urls[0]=/v3/api-docs
springdoc.swagger-ui.urls[0].name=API Gateway Service
springdoc.swagger-ui.urls[0].display-name=API Gateway Service

#springdoc.swagger-ui.urls[0].primaryName=API Gateway Service
springdoc.swagger-ui.urls[1].name=users
springdoc.swagger-ui.urls[1]=/v3/api-docs/users-ws
springdoc.swagger-ui.urls[1].display-name=Users Service

springdoc.swagger-ui.urls[2].name=licences
springdoc.swagger-ui.urls[2]=/v3/api-docs/licences-ws
springdoc.swagger-ui.urls[2].display-name=Licences Service

server.forward-headers-strategy=framework
```

**And finally added the following configuration bean**

```
@Bean
public List<GroupedOpenApi> apis(RouteDefinitionLocator locator) {
    List<GroupedOpenApi> groups = new ArrayList<>();
    List<RouteDefinition> definitions = locator
            .getRouteDefinitions()
            .collectList()
            .block();

    assert definitions != null;
    definitions.forEach(definition ->
            System.out.println("id: " + definition.getId() + "  " +
                    definition.getUri().toString()));

    System.out.println("**************************");
    definitions.stream()
            .filter(routeDefinition -> routeDefinition.getId()
                    .matches(".*-ws"))
            .forEach(routeDefinition -> {
                String name = routeDefinition
                        .getId()
                        .replaceAll("-ws", "");
                System.out.println("Name >> "  + name);
                groups.add(GroupedOpenApi.builder()
                        .pathsToMatch("/" + name + "/**")
                        .group(name)
                        .build());
            });
    // we add services without ws in name
    return groups;
}
```

When running my application:

1. I can reach my user web service swagger when i use the user webservice: http://127.0.0.1:25682/swagger-ui/index.html
2. When I reach the centralized swagger documentation here: http://localhost:8765/webjars/swagger-ui/index.html I have a "failed to load remote configuration"

[image]

3. When I reach the following URL (http://127.0.0.1:8765/users-ws/swagger-ui/index.html) I have "failed to load remote configuration"
4. I notice that http://localhost:8765/v3/api-docs/swagger-config returns a 404 error too

[image]

My issue is:

1. How can i centralize all my swaggers in the spring gateway ?
2. Why do i have webjars in my URL in the gateway (without webjars i have a 404)

Part of my openAPI implementation comes from here: https://github.com/piomin/sample-spring-microservices-new

Comment: I suggest you to check this post [microservices-api-documentation-with-springdoc-openapi](https://piotrminkowski.com/2020/02/20/microservices-api-documentation-with-springdoc-openapi/)

Comment: Thanks for the piece of advice: the link concerns spring 2.x not spring boot 3, so it was partially deprecated. The git repository was up to date but brought "Failed to load remote configuration."... I'm going to update my question with content updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved a few days ago. I simply added the OpenApiDefinition annotation with servers param on each micro services that register to Eureka:

```
@OpenAPIDefinition(
    servers = { @Server(url = "/setups", description = "Default URL") },
    info = @Info(
            title = "...",
            version = "1.0.0",
            description = "..."))
```